# AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66628)

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

In an app that has both microphone input and audio playback views in 2 tabs. No matter what view I enter first, it works all right. Things are still working when I switch to the second tab.

When I switch back to the first tab, the error occurs.

```
ERROR:     [0x1995d4310] 1230: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66628)
Error: Microphone failed to start fetching audio (-66628)
```

No exception threw. App crashes...

Answer (score 6):

It was actually a problem with `AVAudioSessionCategory`.

I change the following code

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
         setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
         error:&error];
```

to

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
        setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
        error:&error];
```

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error also when set 'AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord'. If press 'Home' while recording, the app collapsed. Change to 'AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord'